# Why cant you statically link dynamic libraries?

Tags: static-linking, dynamic-linking

When using external libraries, you often have to decide whether you use the static or the dynamic version of the library. Typically, you can not exchange them: If the library is build as dynamic library, you can not link statically against it.

Why is this the case?

Example: I am building a C++ program on windows and use a library that provides a small `.lib` file for the linker and a large `.dll` file that must be present when running my executable. If the library code in the `.dll` can be resolved at runtime, why can't it be resolved at compile time and directly put into my executable?

Comment: It could be that way. For example, exotic mainframe OS BS2000 has a single file-format called LLM (Link and Load Module) for object modules, executables and shared libraries.

Comment: Okay. So there are formats that can be used to create a single library file that can be used for both static and dynamic linking? Why isnt it commonly used? It sounds very useful to me.

Comment: Here is one reason: on many platforms, PIC-code is less effective than non-PIC code, so for static linking you might prefer to use non-PIC code, while shared objects have to PIC (exception is Win32).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

Most linkers (AIX linker is a notable exception) *discard* information in the process of linking.

For example, suppose you have `foo.o` with `foo` in it, and `bar.o` with `bar` in it. Suppose `foo` calls `bar`.

After you link `foo.o` and `bar.o` together into a shared library, the linker merges code and data sections, and resolves references. The call from `foo` to `bar` becomes `CALL $relative_offset`. After this operation, you can no longer tell where the boundary between code that came from `foo.o` and code that came from `bar.o` was, nor the name that `CALL $relative_offset` used in `foo.o` -- the relocation entry has been discarded.

Suppose now you want to link `foobar.so` with your `main.o` statically, and suppose `main.o` already defines its own `bar`.

If you had `libfoobar.a`, that would be trivial: the linker would pull `foo.o` from the archive, would *not* use `bar.o` from the archive, and resolve the call from `foo.o` to `bar` from `main.o`.

But it should be clear that none of above is possible with `foobar.so` -- the call has already been resolved to the *other* `bar`, and you can't discard code that came from `bar.o` because you don't know where that code is.

On AIX it's possible (or at least it used to be possible 10 years ago) to "unlink" a shared library and turn it back into an archive, which could then be linked statically into a different shared library or a main executable.

> If `foo.o` and `bar.o` are linked into a `foobar.so`, wouldn't it make sense that the call from `foo` to `bar` is always resolved to the one in `bar.o`?

This is one place where UNIX shared libraries work very differently from Windows DLLs. On UNIX (under common conditions), the call from `foo` to `bar` will resolve to the `bar` in main executable.

This allows one to e.g. implement `malloc` and `free` in the main `a.out`, and have *all* calls to `malloc` use that *one* heap implementation consistently. On Windows you would have to always keep track of "which heap implementation did this memory come from".

The UNIX model is not without disadvantages though, as the shared library is not a self-contained mostly hermetic unit (unlike a Windows DLL).

> Why would you want to resolve it to another `bar` from `main.o`?

If you don't resolve the call to `main.o`, you end up with a totally different program, compared to linking against `libfoobar.a`.